# How to highlight each word in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, highlighting

How can we highlight each word in a UITextView programmatically ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't do this using UITextView. You should use `NSAttributedString`.

[Controller for NSAttributedString](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Ali-Cocoa-Classes)

Comment: Thank you very much! Can we give a background color for each word using NSAttributed String?

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to put it in a UIWebView and use HTML to set the background colour of say a  with css.